# Google sheet multiple column lookup

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this:

```
A  |   B    | C
---|--------|---
10 | Item x | 1
10 | Item y | 1
10 | Total  | 2
20 | Item x | 4
20 | Item z | 5
20 | Total  | 9
```

Now I would like to perform a multiple column lookup on this where I give the ID(A) and the Label(B) and get back the Value(C).

I tried this to get value 9 for id 20 and total label:

```
=FILTER(C:C,A:A=20,B:B="Total")
```

But I get `#N/A` no matches found error. What am I doing wrong here?
Hint: the Total entry per ID does only exist one or none at all.

Comment: May be using OR here have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512782/google-spreadsheet-multiple-column-filter-using-or which might get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully execute your constructed formula.

### Screenshot

[image]

Most probably you have either white spaces before or after the text `Total`. You can use the following formula to check the length of the text for a column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(C:C))
```

Removing those will (hopefully) yield `9`. Good luck !!

Comment: ok. it wasn't the text, it was the ID. Somehow google thought it is of type text and wasn't able to find it. When I changed the ID column to numeric it worked

Comment: @BaseBallBatBoy For the next time, it is better to share a spreadsheet with us. This way, it would have been clear from the start. Good thing you resolved the problem yourself and welcome on Web Applications !!